# VS2012 Function Name with Find All

Tags: visual-studio, ide

Does anyone know if in Vs2012, when using FIND ALL, that it not only show "line number" and "line of code", but also what METHOD/FUNCTION the line of code belongs to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, not without using an add-in like Resharper or JustCode unfortunately.